# Error while connecting APNS Server - SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL

Tags: php, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, stream-socket-client

I am getting the following errors while connecting the APNS and sending a push notification.

Errors:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /filepath/file.php on line 63
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /filepath/file.php on line 63
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /filepath/file.php on line 63

My code is:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();    
tream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pemfile);    
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);    
$fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195',
            $err,
            $errstr,
            60,
            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,
            $ctx
        );
```

Seems the .pem file ($pemfile) is not connecting over the SSL.

I am using the PHP Version 7.2.8

Comment: `tream_context_set_option()` ??? Missing `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I fixed my issue by replacing

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
```

with:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer'      => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false
            ]
        ]);
```